# How do I diagnose why Ubuntu is freezing?

Tags: ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit Desktop as a server at home. I run a Teamspeak server, and some php scripts every minute. After 12 to 168 hours (1 week) of being online, the server will freeze. What displays on the monitor is the login screen background, but is completely unresponsive. I cannot access the server through Putty either. The only way to fix it is to hold the power button down to turn off, and then turn it back on.

How would I go about diagnosing such an issue? I am very new to linux and have only been running this "server" for around 6 months.

Comment: I'd start graphing resources using a monitoring system.  CPU, RAM and swap would be where I start looking.

Comment: What do the logs in `/var/logs` say?

Comment: `Jan 31 06:38:01 JacksServer CRON[6065]: (root) CMD (php /home/apache/www/brotherhood/public_html/write_IP.php # JOB_ID_1)
Jan 31 06:38:01 JacksServer CRON[6066]: (apache) CMD (php /home/apache/www/public_html/query/main.php)
Jan 31 06:38:01 JacksServer CRON[6064]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`

These are the last entries before there is a 3 hour break in _/var/log/syslog.1_, between the time it stopped responding and when I booted it up.

Comment: Do the keyboard LEDs react at all? (If they do, the system isn't complete dead). Everything up to date? System freezes might be due to misbehaving graphics cards (happened some way back to me with nVidia and nouveau) or other flaky hardware (or drivers); or perhaps due to some part of the machine overheating.